# Texmaker: how to input “é” and getting “\'e” in the editor window

Tags: texmaker, unicode, auto-completion, french

Ok, this is the preamble of my `.tex` file, that I'm compiling with Texmaker 4.4.1 32bits under Windows 8:

```
\documentclass{smfbook}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

`smfbook` is quite standard for maths in France (I'm by the way writing in French, as the included packages may let you guess) and

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

allows roughly (won't go into the details) to be able to type characters such as `é` in my `.tex` file, which will appear as `é` in my output `.pdf` file. And that's nice.

Now I remember that *under mac* there was a way (thanks to an `autocomplete.plist` file) to be able to type `é`, and to see `\'e` appear in the tex file. (**I need this for editorial reasons independent of me, and it is not negociable.**) Is it still possible ? If so, I would be able to achieve the same functionality *under windows* and with Texmaker (**I don't want to change editor**) because I am not under Mac anymore. Other constrain: as of now, thanks to

```
%\usepackage[mac]{inputenc} % mac
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % win
```

and a comment switch, if needed, I can compile my `.tex` under Mac (where I'm using TeXshop only) and it perfectly works. I would also like the solution to preserve this behaviour.

Comment: The tags mays be off, or maybe I missed the right tag, feel free to edit them if it is the case.

Comment: Your comment makes me realise I was unprecise, I will edit my question.

Comment: Do you want to type `é`directly from keyboard and the editor convert it to `\'e`? If yes, I know that Winedt can do this. Something related to *translation active strings*.

Comment: Yes, but sorry, I haven't finished the edit of my question : I don't want to switch from texmaker to an other editor.

Comment: Texmaker is already set (on windows) to use utf-8, and nevetheless when I type é I see é appearing.

Comment: See the doc here: http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html

Comment: I already look through the doc in fact, and my windows Texmaker is already set to use utf-8, and nevetheless when I type é I see é appearing...

Comment: If you've set *all* your documents to `utf8` they will work with é in your documents (hello from a Swiss guy working on Linux and Mac). There's really no need to have `\'e` in your documents anymore...

Comment: Yes, that is not an answer to my question, as I have precised that I want to have \'e in my documents. I edited my question to make myself even more clear.

Comment: Your constraints (*don't want* to switch editor and *want* to have `\'e`) might be too strong in this case.

Comment: Oh... Can you prove that it is not possible then ?

Comment: maybe you can write everything normal (é, è, ç...) in your text and use a "find and replace" technique at the very end to replace them by \'e, \ `e? Your request seems a bit strange since accentuated letters in the source file is a standard now with LateX.

Comment: @pluton This is not serious ? By the, it is not "standard" as in TexShop, under mac, what I want to do is doable. And many many international journals accepting french article require the use of \'e instead of é in source files.

Comment: but they are not supposed to ask you to write \'e instead of é. They are probably using a very old tex engine they do not want to change. Anyway, your question is not related to TeX but to a text editor able to write \'e when you type é: you should reformulate the title accordingly.

Comment: @pluton I mean, are you really joking ? You mustn't be serious, come on ! With all dued politeness, who are you to say that they are not supposed to ask to write \'e instead of é ? (The answer to a question you don't the answer cannot be that the question should not be asked.) As far as I know, even Société Mathématique de France is asking this to people sending them french articles, and Société Mathématique de France has developped way more sty and packages that you did (and still is), with new tex engines. Anyway I agree for the title, that I will edit.

Comment: @pluton Journals do have strange requirements, and as an author you have two options: accept them or do not publish. So I don't see what you argue over here and why. The request Robert Green made is completely reasonable (and actually, easy to do in many editors). Using search&replace is probably a possible workaround, but that does not invalidate the question.

Comment: I obviously thought of search and replace, but it is cumbersome. But if it reveals being the only solution... I will nevertheless contact the guys from Texmaker, if someone knows, they must know.

Comment: This looks like an editor feature request as it stands. As already commented, WinEdt does have this 'built in' while some other editors may feature it. However, it's hard to imagine it's general, particularly with a move toward UTF-8 input all-round.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially a feature request for Texmaker.